# control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

This code should perfectly run and give the right result but it doesn't. I used the debugger and everything is ok. `c.i` and `c.j` have the right values before the function returns. I make sure there is always a path between start and end so that's not the problem. The `path` and `vis` array are filled with the right values too. So the only problem is when it returns. It gives random, big numbers. It works only when i put a return statement at the end of the function. But i can make a function with only one return statement placed in `if` clause and it works. Is there some kind of rule, so there must be any kind of return statement at the end of a function? To test it, i enter 3x3 two dimensional array with 1's. Any solutions?

Edit: I run it on `ideone` and it works without return statement at the end of the function. Also a friend of mine tested on his computer it also worked. I use codeblocks on windows 7. What can the problem be?

[link to ideone](https://ideone.com/S8wf6m)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct crd {
    int i,j;
};

bool vis[50][50];
int map[50][50];
int path[50][50];

int di[4] = {1,-1,0,0};
int dj[4] = {0,0,1,-1};

int bfs(crd start, crd end, int n, int m)
{
    queue<crd> q;
    crd t,c;
    q.push(start);
    vis[start.i][start.j] = 1;
    path[start.i][start.j] = 0;

    while (!q.empty()) {
        t = q.front();
        q.pop();

        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            c.i = t.i + di[i]; 
            c.j = t.j + dj[i]; 
            if (c.i >= 0 && c.j >= 0 && c.i < n && c.j < m) {
                if (map[c.i][c.j] != -1 && vis[c.i][c.j] != 1) {
                    q.push(c);
                    vis[c.i][c.j] = 1; 
                    path[c.i][c.j] = path[t.i][t.j] + 1; 
                    if (c.i == end.i && c.j == end.j)
                        return path[end.i][end.j];
                }
            }
        }

    }
    // if i put this: return path[end.i][end.j]; it works
}

int main()
{
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
            cin >> map[i][j];
    }

    crd s,e;
    s.i = s.j = 0;
    e.i = e.j = 2;

    int sp = bfs(s,e,3,3);

    cout << sp << endl;


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: seems obvious to me; a non-void function should always return something, every time it is called;

Comment: Put a diagnostic print statement before the closing `}` of the function. Rerun the program. Do you see the diagnostic output?

Comment: by the way, take a look at [Code Complete](http://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670) :)

Comment: Sorry for delay getting back to you.  I can't run the program as requested, because it wants input, and I don't know what input you are giving it.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is pretty basic - it has no way of knowing your function will always reach the return inside your `if` inside the `if` inside the other `if` inside the `for` loop inside the `while` loop. So it warns you that you might not return anything from the function. The easiest fix would be to return the appropriate value at the end and only break outside the loops at the point you now have your return.

Comment: I think your "easiest fix" is inappropriate in context, because the search could legitimately fail and you don't want to return some random value when that happens.  There needs to be a designated no-path-found return value.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a function with non-`void` return type, this functions **should** return a value. If execution reaches the end of the function, and there is no `return <value>;` statement there, the result of function would be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

When you "fall off the edge" of a function, the return value is undefined (meaning it could be anything, including values that aren't valid for the type you were returning).

So, every function should have a return at the end. Or some way to say "I didn't expect to get here, stop now" if that's the appropriate thing (say, for example you were looking for a someting in a list, and you don't expect to NOT find it, then having something to print "I couldn't find , expected to. Stopping..." and then exit the program).

I'm not entirely sure what is the RIGHT thing to return if you don't find `end.i` and `end.j`, but you certainly should return SOMETHING.

Answer (score 1):

You have two bugs.

1. It is fine to have no `return` statement at the end of a function that returns a value, but *only* if the end of the function can never be reached.  In this case, your search algorithm could conceivably fail to find a path (depending of course on the contents of the input data), and then the outer loop will terminate without the `return` statement ever having been executed.  You must have another `return` statement after the while loop, to account for this possibility.  It should *not* return `path[end.i][end.j];`  Instead it should return a special value that means the search failed.  This is the bug which the compiler has detected and is telling you about.
2. There is an error somewhere in your breadth-first search logic which is causing paths not to be found even when they *do* exist.  You need to debug that yourself.

Comment: You all guys obviously missed some sentences in my explanation. There will ALWAYS be a path from start to end. And the code enters the `if` where i test `c.i == end.i && c.j == end.j`. The only problem is when it returns it gives some shitty numbers.

Comment: That's because of bug #2.  There is a bug, somewhere in your logic, which is causing that `if` statement always to evaluate false *even though* there is a path.  So you fall off the end of the function and return garbage.  If your debugger is telling you otherwise then your debugger is itself incorrect.  Here's how to prove it: put `abort();` where you have `// if I put this:`, run the program, and observe that it now crashes.

Comment: Please run it on ideone without `// if I put this`. It works? It also works on my friend's PC. And no, i don't have a bug in my logic because i know the algorithm very well. Also the `if` statement executes. Check that in the debugger. But when executes gives strange results, `on my computer`. And that's the problem. Thanks :)